Trino file base authorization and problem with create role
I installed Trino 455 on the Ubuntu VM, I use LDAP for authentication and file system access control for authorization. I can set rules for users in rules.json file but I can not set rules per role and group. I tried to create admin role with:
create role admin;

but it gave me error:

Query failed (#20240924_155553_00315_ii339): Access Denied: Cannot create role admin
I set full access to catalog, query, schema and tables to my user but I got same error.

here is rules.json:
{
  "queries": [
    {
      "user": "my_user",
      "allow": ["execute", "kill", "view"]
    },
    {
      "allow": ["execute"]
    }
  ],
  "catalogs": [
    {
      "user": "my_user",
      "allow": "all"
    }
  ],
  "tables": [
    {
      "user": "my_user",
      "privileges": ["SELECT", "INSERT", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "OWNERSHIP"]
    },
    {
      "privileges": []
    }
  ],
  "system_session_properties": [
        {
            "role": "admin",
            "allow": true
        },
        {
            "user": "banned_user",
            "allow": false
        },
        {
            "property": "resource_overcommit",
            "allow": true
        }
    ],
  "catalog_session_properties": [
        {
            "user": "my_user",
            "allow": true
        },
        {
            "allow": false
        }
    ],
  "impersonation": [
        {
            "original_user": "my_user",
            "new_user": ".*",
        "allow": true
        }
    ]
}

how can I create roles and groups in trino?
